# Is there a mistake in this special relativity question? Partial derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, special-relativity, velocity

[image: GR Question]

I’m not asking for the answer or even how to solve it — I just want to know if there has been a mistake.

Given
$$U^\alpha = (1+t^2, t^2, \sqrt{2}\,t,0)$$
Show that (using the “brute force” method)
$$U_\alpha \partial_\beta U^\alpha = 0$$
My understanding is that, in flat spacetime, the partial derivative of a $(k,l)$ tensor is a $(k, l+1)$ tensor (from Carrol’s book, pg. 28). If this is the case, shouldn’t the answer be a dual vector, not a scalar?
In trying to solve it I got the kronecker delta on the right side and $U_\alpha$ in the left.

EDIT
What I had tried up to this point included the false conclusion that
$$\partial_\beta U^\alpha = \delta_\beta^\alpha$$
which I think is actually just true for $\partial_\mu x^\mu$ ?

this is what I ended up doing

$$U_\alpha = \eta_{\mu\nu}U^\alpha = (-1-t^2,t^2, \sqrt{2}\,t,0)$$
$$\partial_0 U^\alpha = (2t,2t,\sqrt{2},0)$$
$$\partial_i U^\alpha = (0,0,0,0)$$
$$U_\alpha \partial_0 U^\alpha = (2t)(-t^2-1) + (2t)(t^2) + \sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}\,t) = 0$$
$$U_\alpha \partial_i U^\alpha = U_\alpha (0) U^\alpha = 0$$

Comment: I think that question is not meant to be applied to this U

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent that may be the case, but how could the result be a scalar?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent It works with that $U$.

Comment: *I got the kronecker delta on the right side and $U_\alpha$in the left.* That’s incorrect, but you didn’t show any work so it’s not clear what your mistake was.

Comment: @Ghoster yes with just one single parameter to depend upon, it would work, but we usually have something else. I suppose it is pedagogical enough, since OP is getting stuck.

Comment: The result for $U_\alpha\partial_\beta U^\alpha$ should be $(0,0,0,0)$. The last three components (for $\beta=1,2,3$) should be obvious. The first component (for $\beta=0$) requires a short computation. Do you understand how to get $U_\alpha$ from $U^\alpha$? And do you understand the Einstein summation convention?

Comment: @Ghoster For some reason I thought the partial derivative became the kronecker delta. I added my solution, which I think is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the RHS should be $0_{\beta}$, but nobody does that.

Compare to the homogenous field equation(s):

$$\partial_{[\alpha}F_{\beta\gamma]}=0$$

Comment: Sometimes we use the zero vector

Comment: @R.Rankin which is written as......?

Comment: $$0$$   usually just boldface zero. Bit yeah it's kinda silly in most use cases